# IOS Build for locally testing on my personal Iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, build

I want to know that can we make IOS Build from react-native, as we make .apk file for android to run on my and my friend android cell phones

I want to know that how I make ios build to test my application locally on my and my friend iphone

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You will need an Apple developer program membership (free will let you install on one device) and a Mac with Xcode.